Install driver to show hardware
I have an ASUS TUF TUF F15 FX506LH, I bought it in 2022 in September. Now this year I want to install Windows 11 again with nothing on it, from scratch. I get to Windows 11 Setup "Install driver to show hardware". I went to ASUS Support I searched for drivers, but it didn't work at all, I tried with IRST didn't work, Intel® Rapid Storage Technology Driver Installation Software with Intel® Optane™ Memory (10th and 11th Gen Platforms) didn't work. I tried several variants on YouTube, ChatGPT, ASUS Support, Microsoft Support.
